# How can I rewrite the URL before it's being handled by the http package

Tags: http, url, go

With node/express its possible to do something like this

```
app.use(rewrite('/*', '/index.html'));
```

What would the equivalent in go be? I've tried using the httputil.ReverseProxy, but that seems entirely impractical.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, like going to `/page/id/1` would redirect to `/index.html` or just serve `index.html`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a simple "catch all" you can just do

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "index.html")
})
```

The "/" pattern matches everything.

For a more complex pattern, you need to wrap your mux with a handler that rewrites the url.

```
// register your handlers on a new mux
mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.HandleFunc("/path", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // your handler code
})

...

rewrite := func(path string) string {
   // your rewrite code, returns the new path
}

...

// rewrite URL.Path in here before calling mux.ServeHTTP
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.URL.Path = rewrite(r.URL.Path) 
    mux.ServeHTTP(w,r)
})
```

Comment: Where do i call listenAndServe function ??